# Get day of year from a string date in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-datetime

I want to turn my date string into day of year... I try this code..

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = pd.DataFrame()
data = pd.read_csv(xFilename, sep=",")
```

and get this DataFrame

```
Index Date        Tmin    Tmax
0   1950-01-02  -16.508 -2.096
1   1950-01-03  -6.769  0.875
2   1950-01-04  -1.795  8.859
3   1950-01-05  1.995   9.487
4   1950-01-06  -17.738 -9.766
```

I try this...

```
convert = lambda x: x.DatetimeIndex.dayofyear
data['Date'].map(convert)
```

with this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'DatetimeIndex'
```

I expect to get new date to match 1950-01-02 = 2, 1950-01-03 = 3...
Thank for your help... and sorry Im new on python

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think need pass parameter `parse_dates` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and then call [`Series.dt.dayofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv(xFilename, parse_dates=["Date"])
data['dayofyear'] = data['Date'].dt.dayofyear
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I need,