# Pandas Datetime Index - Extract Week, Month Year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How do i Extract week, month, year from a DateTime Index DF.[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gwMd.png)

In the below image, how do i create a column for week no, day of week, month and year using the S2BillDate column?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html ,if you want use the index: df.index.year , df.index.week, df.index.month

Comment: This should help somewhat on how to play with dates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51063888/get-day-of-year-from-a-string-date-in-pandas-dataframe